# How to validate check datetime input as ISO 8601

Tags: c#, validation, datetime, iso8601

I try to validate an input and then i can get input like that i want to.

Example:

```
if (string != validate(string)) 
       then not valid
else 
       then valid
```

Inputs and expected output

```
2017-03-17T09:44:18.000+07:00 == valid

2017-03-17 09:44:18 == not valid
```

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check valid `DateTime`, you need correct `DateTime` format (i.e `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz"`) and use [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8)  to validate your datetime string,

Try below code to validate your datetime string,

```
 public void ValidateDateTimeString(string datetime)
 {
        DateTime result = new DateTime(); //If Parsing succeed, it will store date in result variable.
        if(DateTime.TryParseExact(datetime, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
            Console.WriteLine("Valid date String");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid date string");
 }
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LUUxWY)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8). This will return `true/false` based on whether it parses correctly. You can specify the pattern to match using `format` parameter.

Comment: If use this format "2017-03-17T09:44:18.000+07:00", what format need i use

Comment: [Standard date formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings). [Custom date formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to match the date format you want (take a look at [this example](https://www.regextester.com/96683) as to what your Regex should look like, depending on the format you need).

```
function Validate(string Input)
{
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex MyRegex = new 
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))");
   return MyRegex.Match(Input).Success // returns true or false
}
```

Comment: If use this format "2017-03-17T09:44:18.000+07:00", what regex need i use